# OpenAI API: How to use ChatGPT Code Interpreter through API?

Tags: openai-api

How to use ChatGPT Code Interpreter through API?

When this works "https://chat.openai.com/?model=gpt-4-code-interpreter"

this returns an error "there are no such model":

```
response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="code-interpreter", # gpt-4-code-interpreter 
        prompt=final_prompt,
        temperature=0,
        max_tokens=150,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.0,
        presence_penalty=0.0,
        stop=["#", ";"]
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: 6 November 2023**

The Code Interpreter tool is now available through the Assistants API, as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/tools/code-interpreter):

> Code Interpreter allows the Assistants API to write and run Python
> code in a sandboxed execution environment. This tool can process files
> with diverse data and formatting, and generate files with data and
> images of graphs. Code Interpreter allows your Assistant to run code
> iteratively to solve challenging code and math problems. When your
> Assistant writes code that fails to run, it can iterate on this code
> by attempting to run different code until the code execution succeeds.

Also, I've made a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/F-KRs6vg4mM) on how to use the Assistants API and posted the [code](https://github.com/rokbenko/openai-api-tutorials/tree/main/Tutorials/2%20Build%20a%20personal%20math%20tutor) on my GitHub profile.

---

**As the error says, the Code Interpreter API doesn't exist as of today.**

See the list of all OpenAI models in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/models).

Also, there's a [discussion](https://community.openai.com/t/feedback-please-make-a-code-interpreter-api/292165) on the official OpenAI forum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I was also exploring the APIs for code interpreter. Got to know about
A) Julius and B) Odineye

Julius is advanced but it do not have API
OdinEye.xyz otherwise, gives API support and have a strong community that back its development. Currently it has feature to upload CSV and analyse the data. I got in touch with the co-founders and they are releasing shared workbench features in next release for development community to participate and contribute. Seems pretty interesting to me!!

API: https://docs.odineye.xyz/